# Xcode 12 Simulator banner reads "MyApp pasted from CoreSimulatorBridge"

Tags: ios, xcode12

Starting in Xcode 12, when my app launches in *Simulator*, a banner temporarily appears at the top. It reads "MyApp pasted from CoreSimulatorBridge".

The banner is styled differently than anything in my app. I am certain it comes from *Simulator* itself. I have noticed it in every simulated device: iPhone 11, iPhone 8, iPhone 11 Pro Max, and probably others.

What does this mean? Does it indicate something bad or is it merely informational?

I did not notice this in Xcode 12.0.1. I first noticed it in Xcode 12.4.

Answer (score 4):

It's the same banner that appears whenever an app reads the clipboard, either intentionally by the user tap doing some kind of paste, or in the background by frameworks that are grabbing the clipboard contents.

CoreSimulatorBridge is the iOS process that is mirroring your Mac's clipboard to the simulator.

If you aren't grabbing the clipboard, perhaps one of the 3rd-party frameworks you're using is?

Answer (score 4):

In my case this was because of an old version of Admob. I went through my game and disabled everything and it only went away when disabled GoogleMobileAds framework.

Jesus Christ, Google!